# Parse Error Syntax Error PHP

Tags: javascript, php, parsing

Somebody help me please, i am a beginner of php programming,

i get message like this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in C:\Users\Sendi\Documents--- Khoreiza\xampp\htdocs\ABRN\content\users\form.php on line 2

and this is the error code:

```
$(function(){
$("#province_wrapper").hide();
$("#kelas").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != 0){
        $("#province_wrapper").show();
        $.get("ajax.php?id_kelas="+$(this).val(),function(anggota){
            var p_html = "";
            for(var i=0;i<anggota.length;i++){
                p_html += "<option value='"+anggota[i].noanggota+"'>"+anggota[i].nama_lengkap+"</option>";
            }
            $("#anggota").html(p_html);
        },"json");
      }
      });
  });
?>
```

Comment: What you've written is Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: The message is from PHP, but you are showing javascript code!

Comment: Show line 2 of the file `Khoreiza\xampp\htdocs\ABRN\content\users\form.php`

Comment: Line 2 is almost certainly the line with `$(function(){`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since that code is not PHP, it should not be inside the `<?php ... ?>` block. Remove those tags around it, so it will just be output literally.

If this Javscript code is in an HTML page, it should be inside a `<script>` tag, so it should be:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#province_wrapper").hide();
    $("#kelas").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != 0){
            $("#province_wrapper").show();
            $.get("ajax.php?id_kelas="+$(this).val(),function(anggota){
                var p_html = "";
                for(var i=0;i<anggota.length;i++){
                    p_html += "<option value='"+anggota[i].noanggota+"'>"+anggota[i].nama_lengkap+"</option>";
                }
                $("#anggota").html(p_html);
            },"json");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Stating to replace `<?php ... ?>` with `<script> ... </script>` given OP's experience.

Comment: @Fred, That would no longer make the code `PHP`.

Comment: OP's code isn't PHP @l'L'l it's JS. Look at the `?>` at the bottom of it in OP's code/question. OP thinks it's PHP.

Comment: @Fred, I was joking. :)

Comment: @l'L'l Mind is tired lol - I'm not my sharpest this time 'o night. I get it now, *good one* ;) a George Carlin type eh?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote jQuery code in `<?php`  `?>` block, you should not do that.

Close the `<?php` `?>` tags, then write the jQuery code:

Here is an example:

```
<?php //your old code

//close php tag
?>

//then start jquery code

$(function(){
$("#province_wrapper").hide();
$("#kelas").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != 0){
        $("#province_wrapper").show();
        $.get("ajax.php?id_kelas="+$(this).val(),function(anggota){
            var p_html = "";
            for(var i=0;i<anggota.length;i++){
                p_html += "<option value='"+anggota[i].noanggota+"'>"+anggota[i].nama_lengkap+"</option>";
            }
            $("#anggota").html(p_html);
        },"json");
      }
      });
  });
<?php ?>
```